# Somar valores no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

No seguinte código, ao clicar no input name "goleiro" ele altera outro input com o valor desejado.
O problema é que eu gostaria de colocar outro campo que calcula automaticamente o valor total (valor goleiro + valor técnico), mas não consigo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function alterarValor(objeto, valor) {
    document.getElementById(objeto).value = valor;
    }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<input name="goleiro" onclick="alterarValor('valor_goleiro', '5');" value="5" type="radio" id="gol" />
<input name="tecnico" onclick="alterarValor('valor_tecnico', '10');" value="10" type="radio" id="tec" />



Valor do seu goleiro: <input type="text" id="valor_goleiro" value="0" disabled /><br/>
Valor do seu Técnico: <input type="text" id="valor_tecnico" value="0" disabled /><br/>


Valor Total: <input type="text" id="valor_total" value="0" disabled /><br/>
```

Comment: Buscando na internet eu já consegui. O que faço? removo a postagem ou devo postar a solução mesmo assim?

Comment: Posta como resposta, vai ajudar quem passar por um problema de somas semelhante ao seu.

Comment: tira as 'aspas' do numero para evitar chamar a função parseInt(), economiza recursos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi simples, eu apenas criei mais uma função, e chamei as duas funções no onclick.
Observe:

```
<script>
function somar(){
    var gol = document.getElementById("valor_goleiro").value;
    var tec = document.getElementById("valor_tecnico").value;
    var soma = parseInt(gol) + parseInt(tec);
    document.getElementById("valor_total").value = soma;
}
</script>
```

E nos inputs, chameis as 2 no onclick:

```
<input name="goleiro" onclick="alterarValor('valor_goleiro', '5');somar();" value="5" type="radio" id="gol" />
```

Como disse, mais simples do que eu esperava!